# Date Calculation Java Assignment

Tags: java, math, if-statement, conditional-statements

Deﬁne a Java method that takes three integer values (a month, a day, and a year) as arguments and 
returns the number of that day in the year (an integer between 1 and 365, or 366 for leap years). Your 
method should have the following header:
public static int dayNum (int month, int day, int year)
To calculate the day number for a given date, use the following formula:

a. dayNum = 31 * (month - 1) + day

b. If the month is after February (2), then subtract (4 * month + 23)/10 from dayNum.

c. If the year is a leap year and the date is after February 29, add 1 to dayNum.

For example, consider March 2, 2000. dayNum is 31 * (3 - 1) + 2, or 64. March comes after 
February, so we subtract (4 * 3 - 23)/10, or 35/10, or 3 (remember to use integer division, which 
truncates the remainder). This gives us a day number of 61. However, 2000 was a leap year, and 
March 2 follows February 29, so we add 1 to dayNum. Our ﬁnal answer tells us that March 2, 2000, 
was the 62nd day of the year.

I keep getting inaccurate results when i test this method i did . If i enter march 2nd 2000 it tells me its the 64th day and if i enter febuary 29th it tells me that its the 57th day. Any modifications to my code that work with the specs of the assignment  and explanation on what i did wrong would be much appreciated.

```
public static int dayNum (int month, int day, int year)
{
    int dayNum;
    dayNum = 31 * (month - 1) + day;

    if(month==2)
    {
        dayNum = dayNum - (4 * month + 23)/10;

        if(((year % 4==0 || year % 400 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0)))&&(month>2))
        {
            dayNum= dayNum + 1;

        }


    }
    return dayNum;
```

Comment: *"March comes after February"*, but your `if` statement only checks for Feb?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but parts b has (4*3 + 23) and after c you have (4*3-23)

Comment: This isn't the reason for the failure - but your leap year expression is wrong.

Comment: Should be `year % 400==0 || year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0` - insert brackets (almost) wherever you like to make this most readable for you.

Answer (score 1):

*"March comes after February"*, but your `if` statement only checks for Feb?

```
if(month==2)
```

You need to check for all the months that fall after Feb

```
if(month >= 3)
```

or

```
if(month > 2)
```

Comment: No.  "month is after February".   Should be `if(month > 2)`